# Is it possible to make sure programs are opened sequentially in bash?

Tags: bash

Let's say I have this script:

```
code /first-directory
code /second-directory
code /third-directory
```

Sometimes when I run it, the VS Code instances are correct. Sometimes they are not correct. The second directory is opened before the first one.

Can I tell the bash to wait until the first line is executed (the first program is opened)?

**Update**
I know that bash is executed synchronously. I know each line is executed before the next line. What I mean, is to wait for the program itself to fully open and then go back to the next line.

Comment: As far as you don't use `&` to run in background, this is the default behavior

Comment: How does this `code` program work? Does it immediately return? Normally, the second command will only be run after the first one finishes, so I am guessing this `code` thing immediately and automatically goes to the background?

Comment: @terdon, if that's the case, is there a way to know about it?

Comment: What you ask for is the default behavior. For example, try it by replacing your commands with `xterm` or anything else that doesn't have any special behavior. If you don't see that happening, that will be because of some special behavior of this specific tool. So please tell us what happens if you run `code /first-directory` from a terminal: does it go straight to the background automatically so you can continue working in the same terminal?

Comment: Can you just add `wait 3` or something similar between each command to make it wait for 3 seconds? Would that do what you need?

Comment: @terdon, yes, when I run `code /first-directory` I immediately get back the console and I can run more commands.

Comment: OK, so how do you want this to work? Do you want all three windows to be open at the same time or do you want the second to only open after you close the first? And what is `code`? What does `type code` show? Is it perhaps a wrapper around VS Code and actually launches it with a `&`?

Comment: If `code` starts something in the background that takes time to finish, then no, you can't easily wait for that in the shell. You'd need some way for the program to explicitly signal it was finished, or some way to check on it. E.g. if the program you started created some file or wrote some output after it was initialized, you could have the shell script wait for that before moving on with the next command. But regular commands don't, so in general that's kinda hard.